# perforce connection

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

this is a real basic question but i was struggling at it from 30 mins.
I am using perforce and i want to access my colleagues workspace for accessing data report which we are working on together.
How can i access his location? he has given me the place where the file is located : //datacell/nfg/depot/src/

I tried finding the user in the user list and was able to find it but not able to connect.
I know it must be a 2 step process. 
Please help.

Thank you and apologise for this super basic q.

Comment: This seems off topic and it's not a clear question.  If you want to access the files on his machine, this is a superuser.com question and it doesn't involve p4.  If you want to access his checked in files, don't use his user or client.  create your own and you can p4 sync ...@<his client name> to get the same files he has.

Comment: I have my own user workspace and am using the perforce client. Is there some option there from which I could search his workspace and connect to it?

Comment: The best you can do is treat his p4 client like a label - if that's what you want, follow jhwist's advice below to learn what you can do with that.  I fear you want access to his files, that means using a file share and this question belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the excellent documentation about [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/intro/index.html) and its concept of [client workspaces](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/intro/01_intro.html#1079899).